# PLY lexer for numbers always returns double

Tags: python, lex, ply

I am having trouble in ply lex with int and double using the following program. DOUBLE_VAL is returned for 1 whereas i expected INT_VAL. On changing order of INT_VAL and DOUBLE_VAL functions, i get an error on decimal point. How can i resolve them ?

```
tokens = (
'VERSION',
'ID',
'INT_VAL',
'DOUBLE_VAL'
)

t_ignore = ' \t'
def t_VERSION(t):
    r'VERSION'
    return t

def t_DOUBLE_VAL(t):
    '[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?'
    return t

def t_INT_VAL(t):
    r'[-+]?[0-9]+'
    return t

def t_ID(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_]([_a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?'
    return t

def t_error(t):
    print "Error: ", t
    #exit(-1)

import ply.lex as lex
lexer = lex.lex()
lexer.input('VERSION 1 4.0')
while True:
    tok = lexer.token()
    if not tok: break
    print tok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar is matching integers with `t_DOUBLE_VAL`.  Change `t_DOUBLE_VAL`'s expression to only match if a decimal point is present:

```
def t_DOUBLE_VAL(t):
    '[-+]?[0-9]+(\.([0-9]+)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?|[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)'
    return t
```

Comment: I want to recognize double irrespective of decimal point. e.g. 2e10 is valid double.

Comment: See updated version. But you can't match double totally irrespective of decimal point - you want to match 1 as the integer 1, not as a double. Note - this form still requires a digit to the left of the '.' - do you want to accept ".123" as double? If so, then expand the regex further. Your regex might also be more readable if you use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` throughout.

Comment: I agree. double must have decimal point to be different from integer. So 5e9 can be 5.0e9 instead. Thanks.