# Generalizing integer calculator example from PLY to floating number

Tags: python, yacc, lex, ply

I am reading the first example from

https://github.com/dabeaz/ply

It is a basic calculator allowing for only expression involving `'(',')','+','-','*','/'`, integers and assignement (for instance `x=3`) and throwing the evaluation of the expression (even it it's result is not an integer, for instance `'3/4'`).

I would like to allow for floating numbers, so that I basically modified the code from the example as follows but it doesn't work :

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# calc.py
#
# A simple calculator with variables.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

tokens = (
    'NAME','INTEGER', 'FLOAT',
    'PLUS','MINUS','TIMES','DIVIDE','EQUALS',
    'LPAREN','RPAREN',
    )

# Tokens

t_PLUS    = r'\+'
t_MINUS   = r'-'
t_TIMES   = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE  = r'/'
t_EQUALS  = r'='
t_LPAREN  = r'\('
t_RPAREN  = r'\)'
t_NAME    = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'

def t_INTEGER(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

def t_FLOAT(t):
    r'/^(?!0\d)\d*(\.\d+)?$/mg'
    t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

# Ignored characters
t_ignore = " \t"

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# Build the lexer
import ply.lex as lex
lex.lex()

# Precedence rules for the arithmetic operators
precedence = (
    ('left','PLUS','MINUS'),
    ('left','TIMES','DIVIDE'),
    ('right','UMINUS'),
    )

# dictionary of names (for storing variables)
names = { }

def p_statement_assign(p):
    'statement : NAME EQUALS expression'
    names[p[1]] = p[3]

def p_statement_expr(p):
    'statement : expression'
    print(p[1])

def p_expression_binop(p):
    '''expression : expression PLUS expression
                  | expression MINUS expression
                  | expression TIMES expression
                  | expression DIVIDE expression'''
    if p[2] == '+'  : p[0] = p[1] + p[3]
    elif p[2] == '-': p[0] = p[1] - p[3]
    elif p[2] == '*': p[0] = p[1] * p[3]
    elif p[2] == '/': p[0] = p[1] / p[3]

def p_expression_uminus(p):
    'expression : MINUS expression %prec UMINUS'
    p[0] = -p[2]

def p_expression_group(p):
    'expression : LPAREN expression RPAREN'
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_expression_integer(p):
    'expression : INTEGER'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_expression_float(p):
    'expression : FLOAT'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_expression_name(p):
    'expression : NAME'
    try:
        p[0] = names[p[1]]
    except LookupError:
        print("Undefined name '%s'" % p[1])
        p[0] = 0

def p_error(p):
    print("Syntax error at '%s'" % p.value)

import ply.yacc as yacc
yacc.yacc()

while True:
    try:
        s = input('calc > ')
    except EOFError:
        break
    yacc.parse(s)
```

I have error :

```
calc > 3.14+1
Illegal character '.'
Syntax error at '14'
```

Answer (score 3):

ply parses the `T_xxx` members in the order of declaration (using reflection on your module). What happens here is that `T_INTEGER` matches *before* `T_FLOAT`. So the integer part of your float is parsed, then `ply` chokes on the dot.

That would directly work if your regex for floats wasn't off (completely missed that point in my first answer, blinded by the obvious wrong order).

I've simplified it to `\d+\.\d+` (which doesn't match `1.` or `.9` so not the best choice), but you can borrow a better one taken from a similar issue: [PLY lexer for numbers always returns double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821234/ply-lexer-for-numbers-always-returns-double)

You have to get `T_FLOAT` parsed *before* `T_INTEGER`. Just swap both declarations to do so:

```
def t_FLOAT(t):
    r'\d+\.\d+'
    # a better regex taking exponents into account:
    '[-+]?[0-9]+(\.([0-9]+)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?|[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)'        
    t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

def t_INTEGER(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t
```

As a general rule for `ply`, do this for all patterns that are longer/more specific than others to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your lex file. First is the token order as explained by Jean-François: the longer tokens **must** be defined first in lex (ref from ply doc.):

> When building the master regular expression, rules are added in the following order:
>
> 1. All **tokens defined by functions are added in the same order as they appear in the lexer file**.
> 2. Tokens defined by strings are added next by sorting them in order of decreasing regular expression length (longer expressions are added first).

But the string defining the token shall be a `re` compatible string. Your FLOAT definition is awfully broken here. If we define a float as composed of exactly one dot, and optional digits before or after the dot and not a dot alone, an acceptable definition could be:

```
r'(\d*\.\d+)|(\d+\.\d*)'
```

In particular, the shlashes `/` shall not be included in the string...

Comment: Once again I fail because of a regex ... Thx a lot !